# Cache URL Request in WKWebView with an HTML string

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

**Problem:**

How can I cache the existing function from loading an HTML string to a URL request.

```
fileprivate func loadWebViewWithParameters(_ parameters: YouTubePlayerParameters) {

        // Get HTML from player file in bundle
        let rawHTMLString = htmlStringWithFilePath(playerHTMLPath())!

        // Get JSON serialized parameters string
        let jsonParameters = serializedJSON(parameters as AnyObject)!

        // Replace %@ in rawHTMLString with jsonParameters string
        let htmlString = rawHTMLString.replacingOccurrences(of: "%@", with: jsonParameters)

        // Load HTML in web view
        webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: URL(string: baseURL))
    }
```

**What I need:**

I need to implement the above function to handle the cache but using the html string. I need to save the webpages to cache but with the above function of loading an HTML string using a system like the below function.

```
let url = NSURL(string: load_url1)
let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as! URL,cachePolicy: NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.returnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 60)
self.webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest);
```